# How to find all social media accounts using telephone number?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, phone-number

My friend had purchased a SIM with new number for himself. It seems that this SIM number had previously been used by someone. It had social media accounts like Facebook, WhatsApp, etc. We have managed to find some of its existing accounts but we aren't able to find all of them.

Is there any way to find all social media accounts like Facebook, WhatsApp, Snapchat and so on related to the phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no central service to do this. You'll need to visit each social media app individually.

Comment: How much social apps are available? Can we get a list of all available social apps?

Comment: https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/On_the_Web/Online_Communities/Social_Networking/