# How to find accounts associated with my Yahoo! account?

Tags: email, account-management, yahoo, yahoo-account

How do I find all the accounts I've created on different websites with my Yahoo! mail account, considering that I deleted most my emails a few years back, which means I can't search up confirmation emails?

So how do I go about finding all the different accounts linked to my yahoo mail email address?

I have tried to search for usernames online to see if any results came up, but to no success. Other than this, I'm out of ideas as to how to find accounts associated with my yahoo email.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related [How to find all social media accounts using telephone number?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102268/88163)